# Rate limiting uTorrent and Vuze on local network

Tags: networking, utorrent, throttling, vuze

I'm doing some research about these two clients and for that I need to have a small swarm (40+ clients) that acts just like a normal swarm. I managed to get some virtual machines up and running but uTorrent and Azureus/Vuze ignore rate limits if the peer is on a local network. I also tried trickle, but that degrades quite badly, probably due to the sheer number of connections open (it never get's over 15 KB/s even if 500 KB/s are allowed).

Is there a simple way to throttle these clients, even when working on a LAN?

Answer (score 3):

At least for uTorrent **it can be done** for local peers (in preferences directly: Bittorent - Limit local peers)